# i want to put a blue selection border when the image is clicked in WPF

Tags: wpf, image

I have got two images ( a car and a motorcycle ) and a text box in my application. When I write car in the text box then the image car should be selected ( visible by making a blue or red boundary ) and the other one ( the motorcycle ) should have a gray effect.

When i write motorcycle in the text box vice versa should happen i.e Motorcycle should have a boundary and the car greyed out.
Does anyone know how can i make it possible?

Answer (score 1):

use an approach like the following in your images

```
    <Border BorderThickness="2">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=targetTextBox, Path=Text}" Value="Car">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Image>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=targetTextBox, Path=Text}" Value="Car">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </Border>
```

You can also set whichever else property you want. **Just remember to set the default value inside your `Style`** that you define the `Datatrigger`s that will conditionally change these values